# C function pointers with variable parameterisation and type

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, game-engine

I'm working on a game engine written in C, trying to use as little of the standard library as possible. For my in game "objects" I've got my version of "abstract" structures, reminiscent of object oriented languages like Java and C#, but I've got a problem when it comes to having objects that do things, i.e. they contain a set of functions. Is there a way that I can store (as a member of a structure) an array of function pointers that is of variable size, type, and parameterisation? Can I give up just one of these requirements, i.e. have all operational functions of void type? Or should I go back to the drawing board entirely? I'm assuming this will have to be dynamically allocated as well, but as far as I know that's standard for these sort of things, right? Thanks in advance

Comment: All function pointers are the same size.  And you can safely cast a function pointer to any other function pointer type, e.g `void (*)(void)` as long as you cast it back to its correct type before calling.

Comment: On many systems, e.g. all POSIX systems, you can also safely cast a function pointer to `void *` and back, but this is not guaranteed by standard C.

Comment: The pointers are all the same size, but the function pointer arrays between different instances of these functional objects will not be. Does this mean I will just have to dynamically allocate all of these things? And would I do that just by having the structure contain a void (\*)(void), have each function dynamically allocated, then dynamically allocate my void (\*)(void) and assign it the pointers to all the functions from before? If so, is this a feasible idea in terms of performance? Thanks for the answer by the way

Comment: I cannot see how you would avoid dynamic allocation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely convert any function pointer to any other function pointer type, so long as you convert it back to the correct type before calling it (C17 6.3.2.3.8).  So you can have, for instance, an array of `void (*)(void)` pointers as your table of functions.  You can dynamically allocate it like any other array.  Note that a pointer to such an array will have type "pointer to pointer to function".

Many people find it helpful to use typedefs to make C's function pointer syntax less confusing.

```
typedef void (*funcptr_v_v)(void);
typedef double (*funcptr_d_ii)(int, int);
typedef char *(*funcptr_cp_i)(int);

struct foo {
    funcptr_v_v *table;
};

double my_d_ii(int x, int y) { ... }
char *my_cp_i(int z) { ... }

struct foo f;
f.table = malloc(10 * sizeof(funcptr_v_v));
f.table[0] = (funcptr_v_v)my_d_ii;
f.table[1] = (funcptr_v_v)my_cp_i;
// ...
printf("Calling my_cp_i(7), returning %s\n", ((funcptr_cp_i)(f.table[1]))(7));
```

If you wanted to define `struct foo` without the typedef it would look like

```
struct foo {
    void (**table)(void);
};
```

Of course, it is up to you to somehow keep track of the fact that the function pointer stored in `f.table[1]` actually points to a function which takes one `int` argument and returns `char *`, and cast it back correctly when calling it.  There is no way to test the type at runtime.  If you should cast it to a type that doesn't match the function it points to, and call it that way, the compiler probably won't stop you, but things will likely break horribly at runtime.  So you'll want to design your code in a way that makes this hard to get wrong.

"Feasible for performance" isn't really answerable; there's no way of knowing what your performance needs or bottlenecks are until you test.  But creating and deallocation such an array is no more or less expensive than a dynamic array of any other type, and calling a function through a pointer is typically only slightly slower, if at all, than calling it directly.

Comment: When you say there is no way to test this, can I not get the type of what it actually points to? While the language may see it as a ( * void ) ( void ), is there no way I can analyse the actual memory stored at the address referenced by that pointer to determine its type? Edit: this is a fantastic answer by the way, thanks for the help!

Comment: There is not, other than perhaps by extremely system-specific and fragile hacks which I would definitely not recommend.